# Error deploying war to tomcat on DigitalOcean

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, war, digital-ocean

I have a war file that I want to deploy. I installed tomcat on my machine and deployed it from the manager app and it works fine. Then I installed tomcat on a DigitalOcean droplet (fresh install). I followed the same steps I did when installed on my machine, however, it doesn't work on my droplet.

I can access the manager app and upload the war, however, when it finishes uploading, the page become unavailable and Chrome shows this message:

```
This site can’t be reached

<website> refused to connect.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

When I remove the war and the app folder from the webapps, everything goes back to normal.

Apparently it enters an infinite loop trying to deploy the war file. This is my catalina.2016-03-23.log : http://pastebin.com/WVkxN6TM

Tomcat version: 8.0.32

Java version: 8

**Update**:

output for `sudo netstat -nlpt`:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State          PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      974/postgres
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:23456           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2645/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      16917/java
tcp6       0      0 :::23456                :::*                    LISTEN      2645/sshd
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      16917/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8009                 :::*                    LISTEN        16917/java
```

Comment: can you please check your firewall settings and use netstat command to check the port number which conflicts with your tomcat port number?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I updated the topic with the netstat output. I don't think that is a firewall issue, as the war file is uploaded and appears on the webapps folder.

Comment: looking at your netstat, you have the same process ID (16917) running for java in 3 occurrences . Can you please check your container configuration port (tomcat container) with java process id? Suggesting you to kill the process id (pid) and try to redeploy and kindly let know the results?

Comment: I have the same issue and I want to ask if you have solved it? In my app I  suspect two things that may create this problem i.e the java version (I have openjdk-7 installed, but i use java 8 code) or my initial connection (on startup) to mongodb, but there is no error from each of those in the logs.

Comment: My problem was that I was using a machine with not enough resources. Upgrading it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as I already said in the comments. I found address binding exception in the `catalina.out`. It was thrown because I used web sockets in my app and in `tomcat/webapps/examples` directory there was a `websocket` example app. The problem arised because web sockets are bound to `host:port` maping and there can only be **one** socket listening on a single `host:port`.